# Spring Data JPA Non-key field references in Hibernate

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

Is there any way in Hibernate that allows using non-primary key fields to describe relationships?

How can I describe Users and Authorities in Hibernate?

When I use `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`, it just helps `Authorities` create a field called `user_id` and it will reference the User id.

**Entity Relationship Model**

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k0eS.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I5WY.png)

**Java classes**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    // ...getters and setters
}
```

--

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Authorities")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    // ...getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@NaturalId` annotation on the `username` field of the `User` entity and then reference that column in the `Authority` entity via `@ManyToOne(referencedColumnName=...)`.

**Example**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String username;

    // ...getters and setters
}
```

--

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Authorities")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = ...)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "username", 
        referencedColumnName="username"
    )
    private User user;

    // ...getters and setters
}
```